# There was a problem updating your profile: Invalid image type

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, gravatar

I can't update/save my profile because of this error message:

> "Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: Invalid image type".

I receive this error message although my profile picture is visible.
During sign up, I've used an email address that has a gravatar image assigned to it.

Comment: Hmm. Yep, reproduced with your profile. It's way late here, though, so I'll take a closer look at what may be causing this on Monday.

Comment: And if you try to re-upload the avatar directly via "Upload a new picture"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Shouldn't be necessary. I appreciate the effort to try and debug/narrow down the issue/find a workaround, but a bug is a bug.

Comment: @Adam of course, just trying to help the OP get his profile updated before Monday. (It wasn't meant as a fix for the bug.)

Comment: I appreciate your quick replies! No hurries though, enjoy your weekend!

Comment: @JanRothen So, good news/bad news. Bad news: it took me forever to look into this. Good news: looks like whatever the problem was got fixed in the meantime. Can you confirm? Thanks!

Comment: @Adam I thought you fixed it, when I was able to save my profile after a few days of frantically hitting the save button. So yes, the issue has been resolved, magically as it looks like ;-). Thx!

Comment: @JanRothen Awesome, then I'll take credit for doing nothing. :)

Comment: @Adam and now [it's back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289342/unrelated-error-when-editing-profile). Any chance to look into it again?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today.  I just created my profile today and dragged an image and saved it with no issues.  I went back and updated my profile and received the same error as above.   I just uploaded a new image by dragging the same one, then voila it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem today. I created profile earlier and added an image. Later when trying to update profile, got same error. After reading [34blast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/345896/34blast)'s answer, I tried something even lazier and it worked for me:

- choose Change Picture
- select Uploaded Picture
- Save Profile

> "Your profile has been saved successfully"