# Unrelated error when editing profile

Tags: bug, profile-edit

I'm trying to edit my profile using safari on iOS 10.2 (full site) but I'm getting an obscure error.

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>    - Invalid image type

I'm not trying to change my image though.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267259/335608) says it should be possible to edit my profile using this method. Though [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63305/335608) has an answer that says it's possible I'm pressing save too quick. I've tried waiting 2-3 minutes before pressing save and still got the error.

Is there a new bug causing this?

Comment: [Happened before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272638/there-was-a-problem-updating-your-profile-invalid-image-type) already.

Comment: @ShadowWizard almost a year old, is this an annual bug? :)

Comment: lol, might be... though it goes back even further...